# Screen turned when writing answer

Tags: discussion

When I was writing this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/98150/16495 just after I wrote "Turns" Drupal Answers turned 90 degrees clockwise. I regret I forgot to take a screenshot :(

Is this some kind of winter bash joke? Joke in FireFox? Or incredibly weird coincidence?

I can't find anything related in site's JavaScript, but that does not mean it's not there, of course. And it's hard to debug when I don't know how to reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: Fantastic, can't wait to find out who's responsible for that one!

Comment: @Clive if it's supposed to only happen once per user, maybe you could duplicate it and add a screenshot?

Comment: Tried it already, no luck I'm afraid

Comment: @Clive stupid me not to take a screenshot

Comment: @Clive it was similar to applying `transform: rotate(-90deg);` to `<body>` or `<html>`, but that renedrs with better quality than what I think I saw. Quality was similar to the one you see when you ask Google to "Do a barrel roll".

Comment: @Mołot, I was also not lucky. It did not turn for me too.