# Random squares when I write - what to do?

Tags: support, editing

I guess it can be considered a follow-up for [Screen turned when writing answer](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2797/screen-turned-when-writing-answer) - now when I write, random squares appear. Their coulor is `#042e4e` as in `background-color:#042e4e;` in site's CSS.

This time I took a screenshot:
[image: screenshot with square]

Now, it happens only in FireFox, most recent stable build. Any ideas how to debug it? Happens only on Drupal Answers. Maybe someone is playing tricks on me or something? Or maybe it's Stack's incompatibility with FF? I have no idea...

It disappears on pretty much any interaction, so I wasn't able to track it with FireBug.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet it's not "Stack's incompatibility with FF", but actually "FF's incompatibility with Stack and other websites". In my experience Firefox has gone seriously downhill lately (having picked itself up again since the _last_ time it went seriously downhill a couple of years ago). I've come across quite a few of these sort of bugs when testing websites in FF on Mac _and_ Windows. You should switch to Chrome, it's much better ;)

Comment: @Clive [I shouldn't have to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/225745). And I'm not always able. It's not convenient to have many browsers, and Chrome's privacy policy is questioned far more often than FF's so not everyone have a choice in corporate environment.

Comment: Wasn't saying you "have to", just that your time might be better served moving to a browser that works properly. If you're stuck with it because of corporate policy that sucks, unlucky. The problem you're going to have here is getting this reproduced - I can't reproduce with the latest FF on Mac, Windows or Ubuntu, for example

Comment: @Clive happens once every workday or two. With couple posts per day I admit it's random and hard to reproduce. Even I can't reproduce it on demand, and I'm using the very same machine and account that was used when it was encountered the first time. So I asked not as [meta-tag:bug], but as [meta-tag:support] in hope to hear a debug / trace suggestions. I don't expect it will be fixed without me reproducing it.

Comment: Have you tried disabling any and all browser plugins (even firebug/yslow/etc) to make sure they're not interfering? It might even be worth posting this as a question on the main SO (not meta) site. You'd probably get a lot of FF users seeing it who could share similar experiences if they've had them

Comment: @Clive I'm experiencing it with FireBug as an only extension. I can't quite afford to work without it at all. I'll try to make myself able to do it... For the main SO, I'm afraid to get downvoted for the lack of minimal understanding and not showing code affected. It appears that debug questions from low-rep users are certain way to be doomed there nowadays. I might have some respect here and on MSO, but on main SO I'm just a noob under 500.

Comment: Yeah, know what you mean. I'd gladly take the hit and post it if I could repro, but I don't fancy proxying a question...too complicated ;)